# What are Microsoft's plans for distributed source control?

Tags: git, dvcs

I've been using Mercurial for some development lately and have been loving it.

I'm curious, is Microsoft using any form of distributed source control internally, and/or are they moving toward it in any way?

I found this article:
http://maratux.blogspot.com/2009/03/microsoft-uses-git-for-version-control.html

It says that Microsoft is using Git for version control, but I don't have any evidence that says it's legit.

Any thoughts? Rumors? Inside information?

Comment: Last I heard, they were using their own TFS for Windows development and most other big projects. I think that article is BS. (Most likely, some MS employees use Git internally for smaller projects, but I highly doubt they use it for Windows as it claims. And MS has said nothing about producing any kind of distributed source control themselves. Keep in mind that they've only just got a full-featured centralized source control solution a year or two ago. Give them another decade to catch up with the distributed thing. ;)

Comment: I have read the same thing (about them using TFS), probably from the blog mentioned by NerdFury. Before TFS, I believe they used a custom version of Perforce.

Comment: That article you linked to even says it's an april fool's joke.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't vote to close because "Question based on April Fool's Joke"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I have heard, a lot of development is moving to Team Foundation Server internally.  This post on the Team Foundation Server Blog supports that: http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2008/08/17/how-microsoft-uses-team-foundation-server-internally.aspx

As far as the article you reference, it makes some statement about it being "April 1st" at the bottom, though the article is dated March 25th, so I'm not sure what the deal is with that. At this point, I would not trust a blogspot blog over an MS TFS blog.

I'm not sure it is in Microsofts interest to provide a distributed version control system. If people are interested, there are other systems that already exist. The world doesn't need to and shouldn't wait for Microsoft to give a system/idea/tool their blessing by developing a competitor to an existing project. In fact, people are so familiar with the Team Foundation Server/ Visual Source Safe methods of version control from Microsoft, that a paradigm shift of this kind would probably alienate their customer base. On the other hand, so many drink the MS kool-aid religiously, and won't do anything that isn't officially Microsoft, that the change would open the eyes of a lot of developers to alternatives.  And how could Microsoft be wrong? They are the biggest software organization in the world.

I have some thoughts on using Distributed Version Control (specifically git) in the corporate workplace on my blog here: http://nerdfurio.us/blog/post.aspx?id=c64bf098-7a5a-de11-aa53-001143eed2d5

Comment: Its your blog, so you can certianly write about whatever topic strikes your fancy. However, as a source of info for others, you kinda lost me right here: "I'm writing this as someone who has never used Git, and does not completely grok how Git or Distributed Source Control works". Come on! At least figure out how it works before trying to tell everyone else that it won't (or will) work.

Comment: I don't have to grok something to understand fundamentals, and Git is only a tool that implements the concepts of distributed source control. Replace Git with Mercurial or Bazaar, and the same argument exists. To grok something takes lots of experience. I was open and honest that it was an opinion, and stated my experience. I have since used Git, and while I like it, my opinion stands that it will be a hard sell to enterprise dev shops. They are happy with TFS, which requires a connection to the server at all times, or good luck getting changed code checked in.

Answer (score 8):

Sure, my article (the one on my blog, maratux) was an april fool's prank... as I said at the end, I just hope they are using RCS... or none at all.... And considering the quality of their OS at least, they are probably using none. :-) I have to start thinking about the prank I will publish this year, by the way.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Have a look over [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2010/01/27/codeplex-now-supports-mercurial.aspx).  It's Brian Harry's blog.  In this post he indicates a) that he is responsible for TFS at Microsoft and b) that they're experimenting (or at the time of writing planned to) with ways to distribute-ify TFS.

Comment: Cool! "I fully expect that we will be adding distributed version control to TFS"

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has announced that the next release of Team Foundation Server (after 2012), and an update to Visual Studio 2012, will support a full fidelity implementation of Git using libgit2, and their Team Foundation Service can host Git repositories right now:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/git-init-vs.aspx